# Can you import data from Excel or WORD directly into CiviCRM?

Tags: import

We have donor lists in Excel--can that data be imported to CIVICRM?

Answer (score 5):

Yes! CiviCRM can import CSV files (Excel can save/export into that format).

For more information, see [Importing Data into CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/).

Please note this encouragement on that page:

> For more details on how to think about your data before importing into
>   CiviCRM, please read the section on "[Organizing your data](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/overview/)", especially
>   "[Mapping your data into CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/mapping-your-data/)".